# About the advantages of using iterative methods for solving linear systems

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

When solving linear systems, there are two types of methods:

1. **direct** methods (Gaussian elimination and different auxiliary algorithms to transform the system in another equivalent system easier to solve)
2. **iterative** methods (Jacobi, Gauss-Seidel, SOR, etc)

I read that iterative methods work better with large system and sparse systems. Why is this? In sparse systems, one would like to take advantage in having many zero entries in the matrix, using it to compute the matrix-vector product more efficiently. But why is this easier to do in the case of iterative methods?

Comment: Direct methods typically have a $O(n^3)$ cost that is prohibitively expensive for large scale problems. (But note that sparse direct methods do exist.)

Comment: In iterative methods, typically the most expensive computation at each iteration is multiplying by $A$ or by $A^T$. The cost of computing $Ax$ (when $A$ is a dense $n \times n$ matrix) is $O(n^2)$. Also, it’s simple to exploit sparsity in $A$ when computing $Ax$.

Comment: @littleO Why is easier to explote sparsity when computing $Ax$ that in the computations that appear in Gaussian elimination or backward substitution?

Comment: Is it clear how to exploit sparsity when computing $Ax$?